# How to change behavior of service according to its providing way?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a MessageService in my application shared in various modules and used by a component which display thoses messages.
By default, I ask people who use it to provide it in the component, so they don't have to enter a key to select the messages they want to display in the list.
If they want to do so a simple boolean on the service tell the algorithm to filter the messages with the key or not.

By default this boolean named "isProvidedInComponent" is **true** since I believe that people do not need the following feature : use case of component A the source of message adding message(s) to component B, the displayer.

I want to know if there is a way in Angular to automatically set this boolean according to the way the service instance of the service is provided:

- True if the service is provided in component (so we return all the messages of the list since they are proper to the component)
- False if the service is provided in a module (so I need my algorithm to filter the messages on a key given, and throw an error if messages do not have one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the flag to your constructor

```
@Injectable()
class MessageService {
  constructor(private myFlag: boolean) {}
}
```

And set the flag with a *factory*

In **module** it will look like

```
providers:[
  { 
    provide: MessageService, 
    useFactory: () => new MessageService(false),
  }
]
```

While in **component** it will be

```
providers:[
  { 
    provide: MessageService, 
    useFactory: () => new MessageService(true),
  }
]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, with an implementation using the configurations of Angular. I found the Angular page explaining this, sad the page wasn't linked in the "Providing dependencies".
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the "providing" of a service is through a module :

```js
providers:[
  { 
    provide: MessageService, 
    useFactory: () => ..., // useValue, useClass, useExisting
  }
]
```

If you wish to setup your service according to a component, you will have to make a factory/facade, which you could call like so :

```js
service: MessageService = this.base
  .withFilter('some filter')
  .withCondition(true);
  // ... And so on

constructor(private base: MessageService) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the façade pattern is interesting (on a larger scale can be used to more than my problem) but I might do not do things well implementing the solution: withFilter and withConditions are function of my service that return itself taking account of the parameters ?

Comment: Yes, each function would create an instance of your service (if none are existing), then return this instance on every call, right after setting it up. Want a demo on stackblitz ?